# Getting Error 403 Access to this resource on the server is denied! While Hitting URL For Accessing Directory

Tags: directory, hosting, web-hosting, self-hosting

I am getting an error while accessing API directory through Domain Name URL.

> 403
> Forbidden
> Access to this resource on the server is denied!

I have already gives all required permission in FTP hosting panel but nothing works it still gives error. Please someone help me To overcome from this issue. Here is sample image example:

Base URL https://api.rupeyo.com/
Just wanted to access directory like this `https://easyimg.io/i?url=glqk0ko4p&name=inventory.png` same as in image.